# WPF reload page with new parameters

Tags: c#, wpf

I am the program is calling from World class to County class. When I satrt country I use it like this:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Country("Italy"));
```

From the Country class I wish that the user can switch countries, but withot calling

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Country("USA"));
```

because I wish to preserve my back option to go back to world. So I need some thing like this:

```
this.NavigationService.GoBack(); //not works
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Country("UK"));
```

But the back not seem to work. So how can I refresh my Country class with new parameter, some thing like this Refresh("UK")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove previous country page from navigation back stack by calling [`RemoveBackEntry()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
//refresh page with new country USA
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Country("USA"));
//remove previous country Italy from back stack
//so that back option will bring the application to World page
this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```